# Why is StereoPannerNode distorting left panned sounds?

Tags: macos, audio, web-audio-api

I'm using some pretty straightforward code using the WebAudio API to play a sound effect in my little web game, and if I try to set up panning, any way I do it, pans that are to the left (less than zero pan value) cause the sound to get distorted.

This happens in Safari and Chrome on my Macbook. I tried playing the sound sample from the Finder (Quick Look, which opens a little playback dialog), and changing the OS audio pan setting, and no distortion occurs when panned fully left or right.

The problem occurs no matter which method I use to create the panner node (new StereoPannerNode() or AudioCtx.createStereoPanner()), and no matter if the panner node is last in the audio chain or not. The only "solution" I've found is to limit pan value from 0-1, which creates a slight panning effect but isn't ideal.

Lastly, I tried making the actual sound sample stereo or mono, no difference.

Here's the unremarkable sample code:

```
function playSound(name, volume=1, pan=0) {
    const buffer = loadedAudio[name]; 
    if (!buffer) {
        console.warn('sound buffer not loaded for '+name); 
        return; 
    }
    if (audioCtx.state === 'suspended') {
        return; 
    }
    const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain(); 
    // const panNode = new StereoPannerNode(audioCtx, {pan: pan}); 
    const panNode = audioCtx.createStereoPanner();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    panNode.pan.value = pan;
    gainNode.gain.value = volume; 
    source.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(panNode); 
    panNode.connect(audioCtx.destination); 
    source.start(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug... As a quick workaround, you can insert a [compressor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createDynamicsCompressor#examples) before or after the panner. Create the node and start with this settings:

```js
compressor.threshold.setValueAtTime(-40, audioCtx.currentTime)
compressor.ratio.setValueAtTime(18, audioCtx.currentTime)
compressor.attack.setValueAtTime(0, audioCtx.currentTime)
compressor.release.setValueAtTime(0.25, audioCtx.currentTime)
```

This is very close to a limiter effect.